# How to apply the AsyncStorage to React Native app for storing data on TextInput and Picker

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I try to learn to use the [AsyncStorage on React Native website](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage). But I totally could not understand the concept at all. I want to use the AsyncStorage for my React Native application by saving the data on the TextInput and Picker after clicking button for saving data, which is also known as "Save" button. Then the next time I open the app, the saved data will appear in the TextInput and Picker. How can I achieve that?

Below are the code of my application project with TextInput and Picker:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  Picker,
  SafeAreaView,
  AsyncStorage,
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';


//Profile page
function Profile1() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>

      //TextInput 1
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Name"
        keyboardType="default"
      />
      
      //Picker 1
      <Picker style={styles.pickerS}>
        <Picker.Item label="Select gender" value="select" />
        <Picker.Item label="Male" value="m" />
        <Picker.Item label="Female" value="f" />
      </Picker>

      //TextInput 2
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Biography"
        keyboardType="default"
      />

      //TextInput 3
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="School name"
        keyboardType="default"
      />
 
      //Button, for saving the data after clicked
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 'Button pressed'}>
        <Text style={styles.button}>Save</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile1} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 6,
    borderRadius: 4,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    marginHorizontal: 12,
    marginBottom: 6,
    minWidth: '48%',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
  pickerS: {
    height: 45,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default App;
```

After adding the AsyncStorage code, it look like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  Picker,
  SafeAreaView,
  AsyncStorage,
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
    
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
    
    // You can import from local files
    import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';
    
    // or any pure javascript modules available in npm
    import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';
    
    storeData = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(
      '@TextInputKey',
      'Your text input value'
    );
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(
      '@PickerKey',
      'Your picker input value'
    );
  } catch (error) {
    // Error saving data
  }
};

retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const textInputValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@TextInputKey');
 const pickerValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@PickerKey');
    if (textInputValue !== null) {
      console.log(textInputValue);
    }
 if (pickerValue !== null) {
      console.log(pickerValue);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
  }
};

saveToAsync = async() => {
 try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(
          '@TextInputKey',
          this.state.textValue
        );
      } catch (error) {
        // Error saving data
      }
}

//Profile page
function Profile1() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Name"
        keyboardType="default"
        onChangeText={(text)=> this.setState({textValue: text})}
        onSubmit={() => this.saveToAsync()}
      />

      <Picker style={styles.pickerS}>
        <Picker.Item label="Select gender" value="select" />
        <Picker.Item label="Male" value="m" />
        <Picker.Item label="Female" value="f" />
      </Picker>

      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Biography"
        keyboardType="default"
      />

      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="School name"
        keyboardType="default"
      />

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 'Button pressed'}>
        <Text style={styles.button}>Save</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile1} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 6,
    borderRadius: 4,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    marginHorizontal: 12,
    marginBottom: 6,
    minWidth: '48%',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
  pickerS: {
    height: 45,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  Picker,
  SafeAreaView,
  AsyncStorage,
} from "react-native";
import Constants from "expo-constants";

import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from "./components/AssetExample";

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from "react-native-paper";

//Profile page function Profile1() {
const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState("m");
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
saveToAsync = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("@TextInputKey", inputValue);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("@PickerInputKey", selectedValue);
  } catch (error) {
    // Error saving data
  }
};
return (
  <SafeAreaView>
    <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      placeholder="Name"
      keyboardType="default"
      onChangeText={(text) => setInputValue(text)}
    />

    <Picker
      style={styles.pickerS}
      selectedValue={selectedValue}
      onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedValue(itemValue)}
    >
      <Picker.Item label="Select gender" value="select" />
      <Picker.Item label="Male" value="m" />
      <Picker.Item label="Female" value="f" />
    </Picker>

    <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      placeholder="Biography"
      keyboardType="default"
    />

    <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      placeholder="School name"
      keyboardType="default"
    />

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.saveToAsync()}>
      <Text style={styles.button}>Save</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </SafeAreaView>
);

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile1} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 6,
    borderRadius: 4,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    alignSelf: "flex-start",
    marginHorizontal: 12,
    marginBottom: 6,
    minWidth: "48%",
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
  pickerS: {
    height: 45,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: Good idea, but now I have 3 problems which says 'storeData', 'retrieveData', and 'saveToAsync' is not defined. How should I fix it? Also, I had forgotten to mention that the data will save when the "Save" button is clicked.

Comment: update your code, ill help you.

Comment: Ok, I had updated the code now.

Comment: @WetzelSchultz I have updated the code.. it will store ur data.... to retrieve use your retrieve function wherever you want.